# Getting last occurrences of specific string in a list

Tags: java, string, list

I have a simple list of strings. My goal is to get the last occurrences of each string in the list by group.

This is mode code:

```
 List<String> newData =  new ArrayList<>();
    newData.add("A-something");
    newData.add("A-fdfdsfds");
    newData.add("A-fdsfdsfgs");
    newData.add("B-something");
    newData.add("B-dsafdrsafd");
    newData.add("B-dsdfsad");
```

I wish to get only the last occurrence of each group. In other words I wanst to get "A-fdsfdsfgs" and "B-dsdfsad" only.

How to do so?

Comment: Loop through the list and split each string with delimiter as '-'. Save the prefix and current iteration string value to two separate temp string variables declared outside of loop. On each iteration check the temp variable value with the prefix from current iteration string . If both are same continue to next iteration . If not then save the previous iterated string to a new list of results.

Comment: Can you explain why `A-fdsfdsfgs` and `B-dsdfsad` only?

Comment: A, B = name of groups. The name can be a full string not only a character. After the hyphen = any text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get last occurrences for each group you can use stream api with groupingBy:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

Map<String, Optional<String>> collect = newData.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(strings -> strings.split("-")[0], 
                    mapping(s -> s, maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(newData::lastIndexOf)))));
```

Note: map has `Optional` as a value

To get it without `Optional` use `toMap` instead of `groupingBy`:

```
Map<String, String> collect = newData.stream()
            .collect(toMap(s -> s.split("-")[0], 
                    Function.identity(), 
                    (s1, s2) -> newData.lastIndexOf(s1) > newData.lastIndexOf(s2) ? s1 : s2));
```

Also if you want to have map values without group name, then change `Function.identity()` with `s -> s.split("-")[1]`

Comment: How do I iterate over the collect object without getting "Optional[someString]"? I need only the "someString"...

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;
class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> newData =  new ArrayList<>();
        newData.add("A-something");
        newData.add("A-fdfdsfds");
        newData.add("A-fdsfdsfgs");
        newData.add("B-something");
        newData.add("B-dsafdrsafd");
        newData.add("B-dsdfsad");
        System.out.println(lastOccurrences(newData).toString());
    }

    private static List<String> lastOccurrences(List<String> data){
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        List<String> ans = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=data.size()-1;i>=0;--i){
            String group = data.get(i).substring(0,data.get(i).indexOf("-"));
            if(set.contains(group)) continue;
            set.add(group);
            ans.add(data.get(i));
        }

        return ans;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[B-dsdfsad, A-fdsfdsfgs]
```

**Algorithm:**

- Move from last to first, instead of first to last because you want `last occurrences`. This will make the management easier and code a little bit clean.
- Get the group the string belongs to using [substring()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) method.
- Use a [set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) to keep track of already visited groups.
- If a group is not in the set, add it to the set and current string to our answer(since this will be the last occurred) for this group.
- Finally, return the list.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to this, as the other answers already show. I’d find something like the following natural:

```
    Collection<String> lastOfEach = newData.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy((String s) -> s.split("-")[0],
                    Collectors.reducing("", s -> s, (l, r) -> r)))
            .values();

    lastOfEach.forEach(System.out::println);
```

With your list the output is:

```
A-fdsfdsfgs
B-dsdfsad
```

My grouping is the same as in a couple of other answers. On the grouped values I perform a reduction, each time I got two strings taking the latter of them. In the end this will give us the last string from each group as requested. Since `groupingBy` produces a map, I use `values` to discard the keys ( `A` and `B`)  and get only the original strings.

Answer (score 0):

Collecting via grouping should be sufficient.

```
final Map<String, List<String>> grouped =
                newData.stream()
                       .collect(groupingBy(s -> s.split("-")[0]));

final List<String> lastOccurrences =
                grouped.values()
                       .stream()
                       .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
                       .map(s -> s.get(s.size() - 1))
                       .collect(toList());
```

For Java 11, the `filter` becomes `filter(not(List::isEmpty))`

This will give you `fdsfdsfgs, dsdfsad`

Answer (score 0):

Using a temporary `Map`. The `List` *finalList* will have only the required values

```
Map<String, String> tempMap = new HashMap<>();
List<String> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
newData.forEach((val) -> tempMap.put(val.split("-")[0], val.split("-")[1]));
tempMap.forEach((key, val) -> finalList.add(key + "-" + val));
```

Comment: Temporary variables and state changes are always bad. One entry point and one exit point is the optimal target.